# How to Create Custom UITableViewCell Editing Transition?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell which has an image & and some text. When entering editing mode, I would like the image to fade out & move offscreen to the left. When & how do I implement this code? I tried putting an animation block in willTransitionToState: but the image simply jumps offscreen w/ no animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `setEditing:animated:` to do this type of thing. Make sure you don't animate if `animated` is `NO`. Like so:

```
if( animated ) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"EnterEditingMode" context:NULL];
    // Set up duration, etc here
}

if( editing ) {
    // do animation
} else {
    // reverse animation
}

if( animated ) {
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: How do I keep this code from being executed right when the cell is created & put on screen? It's being executed right as the cells become visible.

Comment: Isn't it being executed with `editing=NO` and `animated=NO`? Which should just be your default state. Check your logic.